# java | operator is for what?

Tags: java

What is the output of this java code and why ?

```
 int a = 5 | 3 ;
 System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: Run it and find out. Then go back and accept some of the best answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called "bitwise OR".

5 | 3 in bits is equal to

```
0101
or
0011
----
0111
```

Before enums appered in java 5, it was a common pattern to make some constants equals to powers of 2 and use bitwise OR to express both properties. For example, let's assume that font can be BOLD, ITALIC and UNDERLINED. Then if you have constants:

```
public class FontStyle {
    final int BOLD = 1;
    final int ITALIC = 2;
    final int UNDERLINED = 4;

    private int fontStyle;

    public void setFontStyle(int style) {
       this.fontStyle = fontStyle;
    }

    public boolean hasStyle(int style) {
       return fontStyle & style == style;
    }
}
```

Then, if you want to create style BOLD and UNDERLINED - just do this:

```
FontStyle boldAndUnderlined = new FontStyle();
boldAndUnderlined.setFOntStyle(FontStyle.BOLD | FontStyle.UNDERLINED);
```

Comment: Hmm so the setFontStyle function must be written according to that style. For example if i send setFontStyle(3|5) it means setFontStyle(7) there must not be a special enum equals to 7.

Comment: My search started with this statement gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); while studying opengl on android this is not old style platform.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bitwise operator, part of the [nuts and bolts Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

The output is the result of 'or'ing the bits in the binary representation of the numbers.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bitwise or.

I did not test it. But it must be 7.

```
101 -> 5
011 -> 3
----
111 -> 7

1|1 = 1
1|0 = 1
0|1 = 1
0|0 = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The | operator is a bit by bit OR function.

5 in binary is written 101, and 3 is written 11. So 3|5 will give you 111, which is 7.

Answer (score 1):

Its' binary "or" operator in a bunch of other languages, I assume it's the same in java

Answer (score 1):

it's bitwise or:

```
5 = 110
3 = 011
5 | 3 =
    111
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Answer (score 0):

That's the bitwise-or operator.

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/bitops.html